# How to get the files modified in a Git Push?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to get all the files that has been modified in the last Push.

The Push can have multiple commits.

Currently I am able to to get the Modified files of last commit by this command:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
```

Comment: i doubt there's any log of `push`?

Comment: You cannot do that, this is per commit not per push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below:-

```
git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT
```

Or there is a function in jenkins [changeSets](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-) which can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there.
One can achieve this by comparing the current HEAD to the **origin** branch.
`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD..origin/master`

## Example

```
git checkout master
git pull
touch addnewfile.txt
git add -A
git commit -am "added new empty file"
echo 'test' > addexistingfile.txt
git commit -am "added test in existing file"
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD..origin/master
```

The last command shows then the output:

```
addnewfile.txt
addexistingfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`git push` doesn't modify any files.

`git push` adds or removes *commits*.  The commits have snapshots of files.  The commits do not have changes, they just have files.

Here is a file:

```
$ cat name-of-file
I am the contents of file name-of-file.
```

What are the *changes* I made to this file?  I've given you a *snapshot*, and my question to you is: what are the *changes?*  What key piece of information have I left out of my question?

Think about this for a bit, then read on:  Given two snapshots, how will you find changes?  Does `git diff` help?

#### Which two snapshots would you like to use?

The `git diff` command can show you what has *changed* between any two snapshots:

```
git diff <hash#1> <hash#2>
```

Note that you must pick two commit hashes.  However, you can pick those commit hashes by *names*.  In some existing Git repository, run:

```
git rev-parse master
```

and see which commit hash comes out.  Then run `git log master`.  What's common between the output of `git rev-parse` and the first line of `git log`?

There's a complete (if overwhelming) list of ways to produce Git hash IDs in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), but the most useful ones for everyday work are branch names like `master`, tag names like `v2.1`, and remote-tracking names like `origin/master`.  The name `HEAD` means *the current commit*,<sup>1</sup> and you can abbreviate it `@` if you like.

---

<sup>1</sup>The name `HEAD` *also* means *the current branch name*.  The way Git decides whether you've used `HEAD` to talk about a *commit hash ID* or to talk about a *branch name* is that some commands need a branch name, and others need a commit hash ID.  The `git rev-parse` command can ask either question, but the default is to find a hash ID.  You can use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` to ask about the branch name, or, if you're extra-serious, you can use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` for this case.

---

#### `git diff-tree` is the plumbing version of `git diff` for two commits

The command you identified, `git diff-tree`, is a way to run `git diff` from another computer program.  If you're running `git diff` to view the difference yourself, on your own computer screen, you would normally use what Git calls a *porcelain* command, named after the more-polished, user-oriented parts of a bathroom like the sink.  If you're running `git diff` to get differences to feed to another computer program, you might need to disassemble and re-assemble various equipment along the way, doing what Git calls *plumbing*, and here you would use `git diff-tree` to compare two specific commits.

The `git diff-tree` command has one peculiar extra feature: if you run it with just *one* commit hash ID, or a name like `HEAD` that resolves to such a hash ID, Git will extract, from that commit, the list of *parent* commits.  Git will then diff the commit's parent(s) vs that commit.  That's what you are seeing when you run `git diff-tree options HEAD`.

To select *two* commits to compare, simply use *both* hash IDs, or names for them, on the command line.

#### Plain `git diff` can also compare other things

The porcelain `git diff` command can invoke, instead of `git diff-tree`, the `git diff-index` or `git diff-files` plumbing commands.  These allow you to compare a commit's contents to the contents of the *index*, or a commit to the work-tree, or the index to the work-tree.

#### Commits, the index, and the work-tree

Remember that at all times, Git has *three* active copies of each file:

- The frozen copy in the `HEAD` commit is available through `git show HEAD:path`.
- The work-tree copy is an ordinary file that you can see and edit.  Git doesn't really use this file though!
- In between these two copies, Git keeps the copy of the file that it will put into the *next* commit that you make.  This copy is in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  You can view this copy with `git show :path`.

When you run `git commit`, Git packages up whatever is in the index *right then*, and freezes those contents to make the new commit snapshot.  This is why you must keep running `git add` so often.  The `git add` command copies the contents of some work-tree file *into* the index, updating or even creating the index version.

It's the *index* version of the file that matters to Git.  The committed versions are frozen into commits and cannot be changed.  They last as long as the commit lasts.  The *work-tree* version of each file is the one you can see and work with, but it's not the one that Git cares about.  The *index* version of each file is the one Git needs, in order to make new commits—and making new commits is the reason Git exists, so Git cares about *commits* and the *index*.

The work-tree is for you.  Git doesn't want or need it for anything; it's for you to work with, and in, and to copy out of to update the index, that Git needs for new commits.

#### Summary: commits are snapshots; diff compares snapshots

**All of this is how, and why, Git makes *snapshots*.**  Git does not deal in changes.  It makes snapshots.  You can, at any time, *compare two snapshots* to see what's different between them.  What you see will depend on which two snapshots you select.

You can also compare a snapshot (a commit) with a *proposed* snapshot (the index), or compare a snapshot to your work-tree, or compare your proposed snapshot (the index) to your work-tree.  The `git diff-tree` command only compares actual snapshots.  To obtain the other comparisons, you need one of the other plumbing commands, or the porcelain `git diff`.

The `git status` command *also* runs `git diff` for you.  When you use `git status`, it actually runs *two* such diffs.  One compares the current snapshot, `HEAD`, to the index—to the proposed commit.  This is where *changes staged for commit* comes from.  The second comparison compares the index to the work-tree.  This is where *changes not staged for commit* comes from.  Neither the index nor the work-tree have any actual *changes;* the changes that `git status` or `git diff` show are the result of comparing actual snapshots (commits), proposed snapshots (the index), or potential snapshots (the work-tree).